# Redirecting to html page after submitting to flask server

Tags: html, flask, rendering

I'm new to flask, html and java script.
I have an index.html page that can be rendered to another html form page.
My problem is: When I click a submit button, I want to return to index.html.
I couldn't find information that satisfies my needs.
Now I have something like:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/addClient" method="POST"> 
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        
</form>
```

But this allows me to be rendered to my server page.
I want to be able to submit my form to the flask server and to be rendered to the index.html
Also, I have tried :

```
@app.route('/api/debt')
def index():
    file = get_resent_file()
    debt_df = get_df(file)
    debt_json = debt_df.to_json(orient='records', force_ascii=False)
    ret = jsonify(json.loads(debt_json))
    return ret


@app.route('/api/addClient', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addClient():
    #things I do with data from submitted form...
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

But when I do this, I am rendered to :
And I can see a json data, not my web page.

Would be glad to any help!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a JSON because when you go to your `('/api/addClient')` route, it redirects you to your index function which ultimately returns the variable `ret`, which is the JSON that's being displayed on your screen.

In your index function, change the last lime to `render_template("index.html")`. In that same line, if you wish to use your ret variable in your HTML file, change it to `render_template("index.html", ret=ret)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I've solved my question with JS method.
Less elegant, but worked for me.